# Wordpress redirecting to wp-admin/install.php incorrectly

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2

I'm using AWS EC2 to host a Wordpress server with a new Aurora MySQL database, and I made my load balancer redirect to a customize domain. When I try to access the website it now redirects me to `https://www.example.comwp-admin/install.php` which supposed to be `https://www.example.com/wp-admin/install.php`, any idea where I should check?

my wp-configh.php

```
<?php
/** Enable W3 Total Cache */
define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache

/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

//error_reporting(0);
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com');
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');


// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', '**********');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '**********');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '**********');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', '**********');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'MY_UNIQUE_KEY');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'MY_UNIQUE_KEY');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'MY_UNIQUE_KEY');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'MY_UNIQUE_KEY');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'MY_UNIQUE_KEY');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'MY_UNIQUE_KEY');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'MY_UNIQUE_KEY');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'MY_UNIQUE_KEY');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * WordPress Localized Language, defaults to English.
 *
 * Change this to localize WordPress. A corresponding MO file for the chosen
 * language must be installed to wp-content/languages. For example, install
 * de_DE.mo to wp-content/languages and set WPLANG to 'de_DE' to enable German
 * language support.
 */
define('WPLANG', '');


/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

The database is brand new, and currently has no tables. I only created the wp_db_user to access the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me is to clean up the browser cache/cookies. I fixed the url before, but the browser still has the old cookies, and that caused my issue.